# crystal reports, change group name in preview drill down menu

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I grouped my report by ID, but in preview mode's group drill down menu, I would like it to display the user name instead of each ID Number (because it's easier for the end user to understand.) Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: why not group on User Name instead of User ID? Groups ordered by User ID would look random for end user!

Comment: @EmanueleGreco Usernames may be unique, but users' _actual_ names may be the same. When grouping by name you run the risk of grouping two users together who may share the same name. One solution I have used in the past is to group on a formula that prints both, like 'John Q User [100012]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the group name by going back into the Group Expert -> Select the group you want to rename and hit 'Options' -> Go to the 'Options' tab -> Select 'Customize Group Name Field'. You can either just pick the field you want to use as the name instead or use a formula to do it.

Note that this will retain all the aspects of grouping on the original field (including the original ordering), just presenting a new name to it.

Comment: And can also just include the user name, leaving the grouping on ID.  What we've ALSO done, but I don't recommend, is still group on ID, do NOT show the group name, and substitute the user name in it's place.  I do not recommend it because it's poor form and can make modifying/trouble-shooting harder.  :-)